# Making javascript iteration similar to python

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to call `keys()`, `values()`, and `items()` directly on the object, as a sort of shortform of `Object.keys|values|entries(...)`. Here is what I have thus far:

```js
let o = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    keys()   {return Object.keys(this)},
    values() {return Object.values(this)},
    items()  {return Object.entries(this)}
};
for (let k of o.keys()) console.log(k);
for (let v of o.values()) console.log(v);
for (let [k,v] of o.items()) console.log(k,v);
```

It seems to get what what I want with the exception of I don't want that property to be enumerable. Two things related to this:

1. What would be the proper way to make the item non-enumerable (so only `a` and `b` show up as the keys)? Would the following be good enough?

   ```
   for (let prop of ['keys', 'values', 'items'])
       Object.defineProperty(o, prop, {enumerable: false})
   // or
   ['keys','values','items'].forEach((prop,idx) => Object.defineProperty(o, prop, {enumerable: false}));
   ```
2. Would the above (what I think is a convenience method) be considered a bad idea, and if so why?

Comment: I understand that you want to add a property to this object so you can get keys and values easily, but i think the best way it's just using object entries like this: ```for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)){console.log(key,value)}```

Comment: @MatiasCoco understood, I'm just wondering if there's an actual downside of doing this.

Comment: i don't think it's the best way becouse you have to take off the "key", "values" and "items" keys from the object "keys" key. this is confusing, and if you are working with many objects this may slow down your code

Comment: @Bergi yes, and it worked. I meant would it work and be sufficient for my purposes -- I'm a beginner in JS and want to make sure that it's working beyond just a 'console.log looks ok'.

Comment: "*Would this be considered a bad idea?*" - probably yes. If you use an object as a record, you don't need to iterate it. If you use an object as a dictionary of arbitrary keys, you cannot reserve `keys`, `values` and `entries` for instance methods. Only in a few select cases with non-arbitrary keys this pattern would be reasonable. Still, just use a `Map` instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that `this` is not going to consistently point to the object itself, but will be defined by how the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the helper methods to the Object.prototype object (basically the parent of all javascript objects) so that all objects have `.keys()`, `.values()`, and `.entries()` methods.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

for (let prop of ['keys', 'values', 'entries']) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, prop, {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
      return Object[prop](this);
    }
  });
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.keys());
console.log(obj.values());
console.log(obj.entries());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the prototype methods, so that the change will be global.

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function(){ 
  return Object.keys(this);
}

Object.prototype.entries = function(){ 
  return Object.entries(this);
}

Object.prototype.values = function(){ 
  return Object.values(this);
}

const test = {
  name: "bob"
};

console.log({
  keys: test.keys(), 
  values: test.values(), 
  entries: test.entries(),
});
```